# Why doesn't an initialized JavaScript object contain the prototype object?

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

I tried to use the following code to add a `start` method to an object:

```
var Bounce = Bounce || {
    Info : {},
    Game : {}
};

Bounce.Game.prototype.start = function() {
    Bounce.log("Starting " + new Bounce.Info());
}
```

But this results in the following error (on the `Bounce.Game.prototype.start` line):

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'start' of undefined

Looking at the object in Chrome's console, I can see that it doesn't contain the `prototype` object (but has `toString`, `valueOf` and `constructor` etc.).

This is easily fixed by adding the following line before the prototype access:

```
Bounce.Game = function() {};
```

I don't know why this is necessary when the object has already been initialized?

[W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_prototypes.asp) tells me "Every JavaScript object has a prototype", but that doesn't appear to be the case.

Comment: The "prototype", which you thought you were accessing, is actually `__proto__`.

Comment: Is it your intent that `Bounce.Game` be a class?  If so, it should be a function rather than `{}`.  If not, then I'm not sure what you hope to accomplish by setting a method on its prototype instead of directly on the object itself.

Comment: Conceptually, all objects have a prototype, but only function objects have `prototype` **property**. They are not the same. If you read the ECMAScript spec, prototype is usually represented like  **[[Prototype]]** which is an implementation detail lies in the JS engine rather than a language feature. However, in some engines **[[Prototype]]** can be accessed with `__proto__` property.

Comment: @MarkReed Yes. So is the W3Schools statement false then?

Comment: No.  Every object has a prototype.  It does not, however, have a property *named* `prototype`. Two different things.  Yes, this is confusing.  But they are related by the fact that the function's `prototype` property *becomes* the actual prototype for new objects created using that function as a constructor.

Comment: Should really note that `__proto__` is non-standard - there are better [patterns](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+constructor+patterns).

Comment: @Emissary The standardized approach is `Object.getPrototypeOf()`, it returns the **[[Prototype]]**.

Comment: @Leo is right, however you won't be able to call Bounce.Game.start(). check this out: http://jsbin.com/bapuvo/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: @balanza Interesting. The error ("TypeError: object is not a function") reinforces what others have said too.

Comment: Interesting question indeed, glad it's reopened.

Comment: The following answer explains about prototype and constructor functions, it may be helpful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conceptually, all objects do have a prototype, but only function objects (including constructors like `Object`, `Array`, although they don't produce functions) have a **property** named `prototype`. They are not the same.

If you read the ECMAScript spec, prototype is usually represented like **[[Prototype]]**, which is an implementation detail lies in the JS engine, rather than a language feature. However, in some engines **[[Prototype]]** is exposed and can be accessed with `__proto__` property (non-standard).

---

By the way:

1. If you want to access **[[Prototype]]**, `Object.getPrototypeOf()` is your friend.
2. When using `a instanceof b`, it's actually comparing `a`'s **[[Prototype]]** chain with `b`'s `prototype` **property**.
3. And why we say `null` is the prototype of all? It's also not referring to `prototype` but **[[Prototype]]**:

   ```
   Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf({})) // null
   Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf([]))) // null
   Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(new String("")))) // null

   // or shorter like this
   ({}).__proto__.__proto__ // null
   ([]).__proto__.__proto__.__proto__ // null
   ("").__proto__.__proto__.__proto__ // null
   ```

Comment: this make me think about a workaround... I'll write an answer

Answer (score 2):

So, inspired by [@Leo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1032492/leo) comments, I think about this solution to use a plain `{}` object with its prototype.

We have this object:

```
var Bounce = Bounce || {
    Info : {},
    Game : {}
};
```

We define the `prototype` property for the given object

```
Object.defineProperty(Bounce.Game, 'prototype', {
    get: function() {
      return Object.getPrototypeOf(Bounce.Game); 
    }
});
```

Now, we can use prototype as usual:

```
Bounce.Game.prototype.start = function(){
  console.log('start');
};

Bounce.Game.start();
```

Check this out: [http://jsbin.com/bapuvo/3/edit](http://jsbin.com/bapuvo/3/edit?js,console)

Comment: Interesting approach. But why not simply `Bounce.Game.start = function...` ?

Comment: A prototype is meant to be "shared" across different instances, for inheritance and memory-saving reason. This solution is for the problem as @Mikaveli proposed, maybe I'll never use this approach. For instance, we don't know where this code is used and how: if it's in a full CommonJS-compliant environment, I'd rather use a proper module design solution (think about nodejs or titanium).

Comment: @Leo answering your question: yes, it's the same. As you are not gonna use `new` operator with a plain object, using prototype became pointless.